# Speed up Group by in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Hi i want to create an statistic select in postgres

createddate is an timestamp without timezone

```
SELECT createddate, count(*) FROM useractivitystatisticsentity GROUP BY createddate
```

The plan looks like that

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=232569.83..256698.22 rows=1378765 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=232569.83..236016.75 rows=1378765 width=8)
        Sort Key: createddate
        ->  Seq Scan on useractivitystatisticsentity  (cost=0.00..54268.65 rows=1378765 width=8)
```

but the plan didn't change after adding an index

```
CREATE INDEX ysdfg
  ON useractivitystatisticsentity
  USING btree
  (createddate );
```

any ideas how to speed tings up? it takes about 100sec at 1.000.000 rows

Comment: You said at 1M rows, but the plan returns ~1.4M rows. How many rows do you really have at this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen anyone group by a *timestamp* - you must have a lot of interactions if you need do a count for every *microsecond* of time (the granularity of the timestamp dara type in Postgres).

In case you really meant to group by *date*:

```
SELECT createddate :: date, count(*)
FROM useractivitystatisticsentity
GROUP BY 1
```

or if you don't like casts, this also works:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', createddate), count(*)
FROM useractivitystatisticsentity
GROUP BY 1
```

---

If the above doesn't help, you could first try updating the table statistics with [`analyze`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-analyze.html):

```
analyze useractivitystatisticsentity
```

Comment: +1 because I like "don't do this" answers - when they are appropriate.

Comment: -1 This is really an "urban legend"!!! `count(*)` is a special form, it just count it all... Take it off and I'll upvote, as the other part is fine (the correction about microsecond would also be fine).

Comment: the group by microseconds was my problem, i changed it to GROUP BY date_trunc('day'::text, createddate)

Comment: @MatheusOl OK I've zapped the junk and corrected the text (and added some working code)

Comment: @Bohemian, now it is nice... +1... =D

Comment: @Bohemian, one little problem has left... The GROUP BY clauses are not using the cast or date_part... But I can see the point, so it's ok...

Comment: @MatheusOl no, that's a valid point which I overlooked. Fixed that too in case others try to use it - hope you're not allergic to `group by 1` :)

Comment: No. That seems fine now... =D

Answer (score 1):

Query plan depends on cardinality of data in your table - check this [**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/79a39/1). The number of rows is equal in both tables, but cardinality is different, so optimizer choose different plans.

I think it's hard to be more specific without knowing your data.

You may find this links useful:

- [Statistics Used by the Planner](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats.html)
- [pg_stats view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html)